# MassiveJS strange casting error

Tags: javascript, massivejs

I'm new to Massive, but I really like it.  While using `express.Router()` and making a very simple db call:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {  
  db.accounts.find(req.params.id, function(err, results) {...});
```

I obtained an error:

> Error: Argument 0 (conditions) should be type Object, but it was type
>   string with value 2.
>       at Args (C:\Users\JMichelson\WebstormProjects\Proximityv6\node_modules\args-js\Args.js:399:10)
>       at Object.exports.forArgs (C:\Users\JMichelson\WebstormProjects\Proximityv6\node_modules\massive\lib\arg_types.js:7
>   7:10) ...

Which was resolved with a simple cast:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {  
  db.accounts.find(Number(req.params.id), function(err, results) {...});
```

But I find that this casting requirement to be strange since JavaScript should automatically cast as necessary.

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that find wants a number and the params come in as a string so the args parser gets confused. You can use `int.parse` here or do what you're doing. Massive is a bit opinionated in this regard: you can use string keys if you want but you'll have to be specific with `{id:"my string"}.